# How do I close a request to a streaming radio stream url?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am crawling a few pages with requests and came across a url of a radio stream. I'd essentially just like to skip it or do some sort of timeout but the request doesn't end:

```
u = 'http://streaming.radionomy.com/Cheche-International-Radio'
print 'started...', u
r = requests.get(u, timeout=1, stream=False)
```

I thought that setting stream=False would do that, no? I've also tried to set the header headers['Connection'] = 'close' but that doesn't work either. In both cases the request doesn't close.

Thanks!

Comment: I red something about contextlib https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the code is behaving as expected, but maybe the parameters does not mean what you would expect. `timeout` is a time limit for how long does it takes for the server to start sending the response, but the server you are accessing does not take long to start responding... but it sends an infinite response. `stream`, on the other hand, when set to `true` (which is the default), waits until the whole content has been downloaded; again, the content does not ever end, so the call will never return (and will probably eat your RAM).

I think that what you need is to make a request with `stream=False`, take a look at the response HTTP headers, and discard the request if the content is not what you are looking for. You may look, for example, at `Content-Type`; the following code will work if you are interested only in `text/html` responses:

```
u = 'http://streaming.radionomy.com/Cheche-International-Radio'
print 'started...', u
r = requests.get(u, stream=True)
content_type = r.headers['Content-Type']
if content_type.startswith('text/html'):
    content = r.content
    # process the content
else:
    print 'discarded ', u
```

Of course, you may choose the filter the requests with some other criteria. For your example, the headers are:

```
{
    'Expires': 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
    'icy-br': '128, 128',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'icy-name': 'ChecheInternationalRadio',
    'ice-audio-info': 'bitrate=128;samplerate=44100;channels=2',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'icy-genre': 'medellin',
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    'icy-description': 'Esta es una Emisora suena solo Exitos Una selecta programacion musical con los mejores artistas y canciones de todos los tiempos. Transmitiendo desde medellin Colombia.',
    'icy-pub': '1',
    'Accept-Ranges': 'none',
    'icy-url': 'http://cheche-international-radio.playtheradio.com/',
    'Server': 'Icecast 2.3.3-kh8'
}
```

Some of them are standard and some of the are particular to [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/), choose what works better for you.